# Brace Expansion not working bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, brace-expansion

I am trying to use brace expansion in a bash script as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
document_root="/var/www/www.example.com"
`chmod -R g+w $document_root/{../captcha,../files}`
```

this gives me the error

> chmod: cannot access `/var/www/www.example.com/{../captcha,../files}': No
>   such file or directory

but when I run this in a terminal it works just fine.

Comment: Is this a copy and paste or a retype? The result you are getting looks like you have quoted the brace expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
document_root="/var/www/www.example.com"
chmod -R g+w $document_root/{../captcha,../files}
```

1. Don't prefix a variable with `$` when you are *assigning* to a variable, only when expanding
2. You don't need the backticks around chmod, doing so treats the whole thing as a command

Comment: removing backqoutes gave the exact same result

Comment: oh sorry. It was a typo in the question not the actual code. corrected it.

Comment: What is the result of `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: What do you see if you stick an `echo` infront of the `chmod`? Does it expand?

Comment: Ya, works here too. Brace expansion was introduced in `3.0-alpha` so not sure what's up

Comment: SiegeX was correct. it was just careless me who changed one version and tested another version. I apologize for my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way?

```
#!/bin/bash
document_root="/var/www/www.example.com"
chmod -R g+w $document_root/{"../captcha","../files"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled over this issue myself. In my case I was using `set -eu` command at some point of my script resulting in this particular issue. Fix was to add `-B` option like `set -euB` re-enabling brace expansion for it has been disabled for some reason though manual states it is enabled by default.